# How to grab item outside of tag using python+beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using python+beautifulsoup, let's say I have a `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` object, `a`:

```
<div class="class1"><em>text1</em> text2</div>
```

I can use the following command to extract `text1 text2` and put it in `b`:

```
b = a.text
```

I can use the following command to extract `text1` and put it in `c`:

```
c = a.findAll("em")[0].text
```

But how can I extract just `text2`?

Comment: Do you want to ignore div's children content?

Comment: Maybe try `d = b[len(c):]`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your HTML snippet slightly to have more than just one word in and outside the `<em>` tag so that [`getText()`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) extracting all the text form your `<div>` container leads to the following output:

```
'text1 foo bar text2 foobar baz'
```

As you can see, this is just a string where the `<em>` tags have been removed. As far as I understood you want to kind of remove the contents of the `<em>` tag from the contents in your `<div>` container.

My solution is not very nice, but this can be done by using [`.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) to replace the contents of the `<em>` tag with an empty string `''`. Since this could lead to leading or trailing spaces you could call [`.lstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to get rid of those:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# coding: utf-8

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="class1"><em>text1 foo bar</em> text2 foobar baz</div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

result = soup.getText().replace(soup.em.getText(), '').lstrip()

print(result)
```

Output of print statement:

```
'text2 foobar baz'
```

Comment: Suppose that `text1` can actually be an unknown number of words. Same with `text2`.

Comment: Why on earth would you always assume there are only two words, especially given that the OP's snippet is obviously an example ("text1 text2")?

Comment: @bill999: I updated my answer to fulfill the 'more than one/two words problem'

Answer (score 2):

You can remove all children of the div parent and then get the content of the parent like this:

```
>>> a = BeautifulSoup(out_div, 'html.parser')
>>> for child in a.div.findChildren():
...     child.replace_with('')
...     
<em>text1</em>
>>> a.get_text()
u' text2'
```